# Is `PartialFunction extends Function` a violation of LSP?

Tags: scala, liskov-substitution-principle

The Liskov Substitution Principle state that

> if `S` is a subtype of `T`, then objects of type `T` may be replaced with objects of type `S` without altering any of the desirable properties of that program.

However, in Scala, there is the `PartialFunction` that is not applicable/defined in all cases.

```
trait Function1 {
  def apply(x: A): R
}

trait PartialFunction extends Function1 {
  def apply(x: A): R
  def isDefinedAt(x: A): Boolean
}
```

If you apply a `PartialFunction` to an undefined value, you will receive an exception.

A convenient way to create a `PartialFunction` in scala is to use pattern matching. Doing so, you receive a `MatchError` for undefined values.

```
val fn:Function1[String, Int] = s => s.length

val pf:PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
  case "one" => 3
}

def program(f:Function1[String, Int], s:String):(Boolean, Int) = (
  f.isInstanceOf[Function1[String, Int]], f(s)
)

program(fn, "one") == program(pf, "one")
program(fn, "two") == program(pf, "two")
```

> fn: String => Int = <function1>
>
> pf: PartialFunction[String,Int] = <function1>
>
> program: program[](val f: String => Int,val s: String) => (Boolean, Int)
>
> res0: Boolean = true
>
> scala.MatchError: two (of class java.lang.String)
>
> at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(delme.sc:249)
>
> at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(delme.sc:247)
>
> at ...

Both `fn` and `pf` are subtypes of `Function1`, but I cannot substitute `fn` by `pf`without altering my `program`. So in my opinion it is a violation of LSP.

What do you think ?

Comment: This is going to be primarily an opinion piece. Do you have a more specific question regarding application or use of the more general question you're asking?

Comment: Absolutely not. I was just asking for advice from other developers. Maybe should I have posted it on another community ?

Comment: You could also define a `Function1` that simply throws exceptions for all inputs other than `"one"`. Your argument for violating LSP is that throwing an exception may be an undesirable alteration, but a `Function1` can still have inputs that throw exceptions. e.g. `BigDecimal("abc")`. The main difference between `PartialFunction` and `Function1` is that you have a built-in way of checking whether or not elements are defined first.

Comment: No languages can prevent user mistakes. If someone want to break his program he can always do it. My concerns is more than in my opinion, Scala (the language itself) is violating the LSP. That will never make it less "cool" but I was just wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fn` and `pf` are not subtypes of `Function1`, since they aren't types at all. They are values, and LSP doesn't say you can take any object of type `T` and replace it with any object of type `S`: `Int` is certainly a subtype of `Int`, but replacing `1` with `2` can make a correct program incorrect.

`PartialFunction[String, Int]` is a subtype of `Function1[String, Int]`, but the contract of `Function1` doesn't forbid `apply` from throwing exceptions and in fact explicitly allows it:

> Apply the body of this function to the argument. **It may throw an exception.**

So if your program can handle objects of type `Function1[A, B]`, it has to deal with `apply` throwing exceptions in some way already and `PartialFunction` throwing a `MatchError` is just a specific case.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia there is an additional clause required for the LSP to apply.

> No new exceptions should be thrown by methods of the subtype, except where those exceptions are themselves subtypes of exceptions thrown by the methods of the supertype.

So (assuming wikipedia is correct), no PartialFunction doesn't violate the LSP since it doesn't apply to this case.

EDIT: There is additional info in the scaladoc: ([Scaladoc Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Function1.html))

> Note that Function1 does not define a total function, as might be suggested by the existence of PartialFunction. The only distinction between Function1 and PartialFunction is that the latter can specify inputs which it will not handle.

So another way of thinking about it would be that pf is not a subtype of fn.

fn: String => Int

pf: Subset of String => Int

Further edit in response to Comment:
No I'm arguing that the LSP doesn't apply at all. For the LSP to apply S must not throw new exceptions. S here does throw new exceptions so the LSP cannot be violated since it doesn't apply.

Comment: But `PartialFunction` throws a `scala.MatchError` which `Function` doesn't? Or are you arguing that `Function` can throw anything? Sure, exceptions are not really expressed in the type here, so it could be either.

Comment: I've put in some more stuff. My knowledge of the foundations of type theory is next to non existent however so I'm very much open to being completely wrong.

Comment: Ah, I understood your quote as the LSP being *violated* with such an exception behaviour, instead of not applying at all.

Comment: I don't agree: 1. this clause _is_ satisfied, because `Function1#apply` can indeed throw any exception. Since Scala doesn't have checked exceptions, the only way in which it could be violated is if it was _documented_ not to throw, but it is explicitly allowed.

Comment: 2. Those aren't conditions for LSP to apply at all, but to hold (necessary, but not sufficient). I.e. if the clause weren't satisfied, it _would_ be a violation of LSP.